# DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block - in incognite mode but no error in normal

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i am getting this error in the incognite mode of chrome : 
DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

But, in the normal mode,  i am not getting this error .

I am getting this error at request.session.save from some middleware .

Upgraded to 1.4.2 from 1.3 recently.

Regarding session backends, I set it as database backend. When I changed to cache backend, it is not giving error .

Comment: it is difficult to give any advice based on this information. it looks like you are using the database session backend. could you try it with django devserver https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver and tell us what sql querys have made your transaction crash?

Comment: Upgraded to 1.4.2 from 1.3 recently.

Regarding session backends, I set it as database backend. When I changed to cache backend, it is not giving error .

Answer (score 1):

You see in incognito mode, chrome automatically delete cookie files, while django session mechanism store session id and csrf token in cookie.

You can't use standart django session mechanism with deleting cookie. But [there](http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/cookieless-django-sessions-and-authentication-with) is some methods to implement session without cookie.